# How to append the new records to the existing CSV file in SAS

Tags: sas, proc-sql

When I run my code the first time, I am outputting a new dataset with one row in the folder. Then I use the new value for the variable and run it again, my intention is to append the new record as the second row in the dataset which I created the first time.

Suppose that I have a variable called `name`, which is used to change its values multiple times, I also have a table called `tab1`, which is used to store the new values every time `name` has new value. For example: in the code:

```
PROC SQL;
Create table tab1 AS
select a.name, a. id
from tab2 a ;
quit;
```

at the first time, if `name` variable is "Mark", then `tab1` stores the values Mark and 2, then I use PROC EXPORT to output a new dataset with one row, which includes name: Mark and id: 1. For example:

```
PROC EXPORT data = tab1
outfile = "&somepath\table1.csv"
replace;
run;
```

Then I read this table1.csv, then use it to union tab1 again to get a new table `tab3`, then output it in the folder, for example:

```
PROC IMPORT OUT=table1
datafile = "&somepath\table1.csv"
replace;
run;


PROC SQL;
create table tab3 as
select * 
from table1
union
select *
from tab1;
quit;

PROC EXPORT data=tab3
outfile = "&somepath\table1.csv
replace;
run;
```

The problem is that every time I run the code, the output will be updated. for example, `name` variable is set to "Tom", then `tab1` will become "Tom and 2, so is table1. I just cannot append the new one to the old ones. How should I revise my code to do that?

Comment: You seem to be creating text files instead of datasets. Is there a reason for that?  Is your goal to append records to an existing CSV file?

Comment: @Parfait, I know the logic is pretty messy, for example:`name` = "Mark", then `tab1`= Mark and 1;  table1.csv = Mark and 1; `tab3`= Mark and 1, Mark and 1; updated table1.csv = Mark and 1, Mark and 1; When you run the code with the new `name` = "Tom", we will get `tab1`= Tom and 2;  table1.csv = Tom and 2; `tab3`= Tom and 2, Tom and 2; updated table1.csv = Tom and 2, Tom and 2; The desired output I want is  updated table1.csv = Mark and 1, Tom and 2. Hope it makes sense

Comment: @Tom Yes, that is what I intend to do. Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use PROC EXPORT to write delimited records. Just use a normal data step. That way you can control the options on the FILE statement and include the MOD option so that SAS will append to the existing file.

```
 data _null_;
    set new_dataset;
    file 'existing.csv' dsd MOD ;
    put (_all_) (+0) ;
 run;
```

If you want your CSV file to have a header row you could use PROC EXPORT the first time or just write the header yourself.

```
 proc transpose data=table1(obs=0) out=names ;
    var _all_;
 run;
 data _null_;
   file 'newfile.csv' dsd ;
   set names end=eof;
   put _name_ @;
   if eof then put;
 run;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion. it really save my day :)